Guidance on an Automatic Stamp Machine with Rotating Digits
I am a beginner in engineering, and I am currently working on a project to create an automatic stamp machine that features 10 rotating digits, each controllable with an electric motor. I have already created a prototype in Blender, but I am unsure about its optimization and functionality.


Here's the requirements for this machine:

Objective: Develop a numeric stamp that is fully controllable via computer.
Application: The machine will be used to print a specified 10-digit number (not an incremented serial number) on paper. This method is chosen because other printing techniques do not provide the same level of accuracy and consistency under magnification.
Performance: The machine must achieve a minimum printing speed of 50 pages per minute (ppm) for printing a single 10-digit number on each sheet.
Operations: The user will input the desired number (e.g., 0002345189) through software running on a Raspberry Pi. The machine will then adjust the digits accordingly and print them on standard linen paper by applying light pressure to ensure clear and precise printing.
Materials: The materials for construction are to be determined, but aluminum is currently considered for its lightweight and durability properties.
Digit size [mm]:

Width: 1.5
Height: 2.5
Depth: 3



My goal is to have each digit controlled separately using electrical motors. However, I am looking for guidance on the following:

Existing Examples: Are there any existing projects or examples that I can reference?

Motor Selection: What types of motors would be best suited for this application, considering factors like precision and control?

Control Mechanism: What are some effective ways to control the motors for precise digit rotation?

Optimization Tips: Any tips on optimizing the design for better performance and reliability?



So when you researched how serial numbers are added to things, what did you find? Would it be easier / faster to cut with a laser?

Why is it a design requirement to have independent motors/control? Is it critical to be able to change each digit independently, e.g. to be able to get between any possible number in a set (and really short) amount of time? If the numbers are only ever incremental, you can do this with only one motor (think of how tally clickers work). Maybe it only needs a manual override to disengage the motor, and set it to where you want to start incrementing from? Etc. etc. You need to get your requirements straight.

@JonathanRSwift I have indeed updated the requirements to be more precise. I want control over each digit because this is not an incremented number. If there is only one motor, it would take a long time to reach large numbers within a limited timeframe. I appreciate your idea of a manually movable motor, but it may not be the best option for the speed I want to achieve (see the updated post).

The specification helps a lot. What does the 3 mm depth refer to? The "stroke" (travel) of the stamp? Or the depth of penetration!? I think you are describing "embossing" the paper with the number. Emboss: "carve, mould, or stamp (a design) on a surface or object."

@Transistor The depth refer to the distance between the face of the rotating circle and the contact point of the digit with the paper. [illustration]https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1292503234258272288/1313571910654758992/image.png?ex=67509eac&is=674f4d2c&hm=cbf32121fc4420c50d1dd5ce46fcc6b0e3323717427a0bab542fc539f9589f46&

Consider using a Geneva drive to rotate your digits, advancing one position per rotation of the motor shaft. It would eliminate the need for a separate locking mechanism while making the impression.

There are a number of potential solutions to your problem but I think you should take a step back and write a User Requirement Specification first. This will clarify your thinking, eliminate several options and narrow down your search and design choices. You can edit your original question with the new information.

What material is being marked?
What font size?
How many characters? (You've given this information: 10.)
What is the maximum time allowed per part marking?
Are the numbers sequential or can be chosen at random?
If they are sequential is a reset to 0 or 1 required?
What technologies have you ruled out? (Inkjet, thermal transfer, laser engraving, CNC engraving, impact dot-matrix, etc., and why.)
What will control the number stamp? (PLC, hobby board, computer, ...)

For example, if you have a few seconds or more to do the job it may be possible to have one stamp wheel mounted on a lead screw so that the numbers can be stamped in sequence. This would require only two stepper motors. The URS is your friend here.

Based on your URS edit, and your one-page-per-second (approx.) requirement you can't just use a single wheel stamping in multiple positions.
An Internet image search shows manual-set stampers such as this one and others with automatic indexing.

Figure 1. Manual set numerical embosser. Image source: Infinity Stamps.
There are a few interesting design points here which are employed by many other companies making similar devices.

The numbers don't have square edges (which your sketches do) so they emboss without cutting the material being marked.
You can read the current setting '12345'. Note the the '1' is between 4 and 5 so the read position is 4½ steps from the stamp position.
There's a nice concave section between each of the embossing digits. This is probably used by a roller clamp to hold the wheels in position once set.

It seems to me that a series of small impulse solenoids could be used to advance the numbers quite quickly 1/10 of a turn per impulse. Issues to be resolved would include:

Home sensors for each wheel. (This would be a problem on a motor driven system too.)
Individual spring rollers to act as detent stops for each digit. These might be lifted by the solenoids during rotation to prevent damage to the digits and to reduce friction.
On power-up the system would index each wheel to the home position ('0' seems a good choice) and then advance to the required digit. The controller would keep track of the position and minimise the number of indexes going from one 10-digit number to the next.
The system could check that the home sensor comes on anytime a digit rolls over and alarm if an error is detected.
Control would be ten digital IO pins rather than ten motor drivers. Ten solenoid wires and a common return.


Figure 2. Solenoid and ratchet. Image source: YouTube.
The video doesn't give any detail but it may give you some ideas.

Thank you for your recommendations! I've edited my post based on your suggestions.
